# Azure Monitoring Logs VS Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

I am trying to understand difference between Azure Log Analytics and Azure Data Explorer(ADX). While reading the documentation what I understood is that the Log Analytics is the web tool for creating/editing queries to pull data from Azure Monitoring Logs, data is collected by azure's monitoring logs and stored in workspaces which can be queried using log analytics KQL. What confuses me is [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-platform-logs#relationship-to-azure-data-explorer) in documentation, as per this, Monitoring Logs are similar to ADX, data is stored similarly in tables and uses same KQL to query the data.

Can someone help in understanding the differences.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Log Analytics is built on top of Azure Data Explorer (ADX). Various Azure services know to stream data into Log Analytics, that this data can then be queried using KQL (Kusto Query Language).

Comment: Is it possible to use [ADX deletion methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/delete-data) for Log Analytics?

Comment: No. Log Analytics only allows queries (while data deletion requires running control commands).